# is it right when i want to view some maximum value from database MySql using Java Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, max

```
public Double maksimal1() {
    double m1 = 0;
    query = "SELECT MAX(`K1`) FROM penilaian ";
    status = koneksi.eksekusiQuery(query, true);
    if(status){
        rsMatriks = koneksi.getRs();
        try{
            rsMatriks.next();
            m1= rsMatriks.getDouble("K1");
            rsMatriks.close();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
    return m1;
}
```

Comment: Apparently your code somehow does not work since you ended up posting it to StackOverflow, so to answer your question, no, that's not right. :) It'd be cool if you could replace that `return null` with a `throw new RuntimeException(ex);` and then let us know what you get when you execute that code again!

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns 1 column which you should alias as `K1` if you want to access it by name:

```
query = "SELECT MAX(`K1`) AS K1 FROM penilaian";
```

or if you want to access it by its index which is `1` since it is the only column:

```
m1 = rsMatriks.getDouble(1);
```